# How to open browser and navigate to a webpage with air for android?

Tags: android, flash, air

I'm programming for android with flash in Actionscript 3.0. I need to navigate to a webpage after user touches the button. Something like this:

```
button.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, fl_TapHandler);
function fl_TapHandler(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    WebBrowser.Navigate("http://www.webpage.com/");
}
```

I don't know this function D: . Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be like this

```
button.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, fl_TapHandler);
function fl_TapHandler(event:TouchEvent):void
{
   var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.webpage.com/");
    navigateToURL(request);
}
```

The [`navigateToURL`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL()) method is a part of the `flash.net` package.